# Trying to pull most recent pay rate from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just stuck on something that seems so simple, but I can't figure out the syntax. I've a got a table of pay rates, associated with dates the rates changed, and employee ids.  multiple records per employee.

I'm trying to get a list of the most recent date, and the wage from only that date.  I've tried:
SELECT MAX(Date), Rate, EmpID FROM History

but that doesn't work. It seems to return a record for each pay rate.

How would others do this efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the latest `Rate` for each `EmpID`.

```
select [Date],
       Rate,
       EmpID
from (select [Date],
             Rate,
             EmpID,
             row_number() over(partition by EmpID order by [Date] desc) as rn
      from History) as H
where rn = 1
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109020/

Comment: In general I've found ROW_NUMBER() to perform better than a correlated aggregated subquery.

Comment: This works well.  Thank you.  I've never used ROW_NUMBER() before.  It's a good lesson is "What I don't know won't hurt me, (but will make it harder)"

Comment: I should say, I was able to get this to work with MAX(date) in sub queries, but it's not worth the mess. Using ROW_NUMBER() is much better. Also, part of what was throwing me was the date field was varchar, so neither this solution or my MAX() sub-queries were working as expected. Once I caught that and CAST([Date] as datetime), it worked. I thought I had checked that data type prior to posting, but I should double checked. I'm glad I didn't though, because like I said, Mikael Eriksson's suggestion is SO much better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Date, Rate, EmpID
FROM   History A
WHERE  Date = (
           SELECT Max(Date)
           FROM   History B
           WHERE  A.EmpID = B.EmpId )
```

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - I don't think this works, since many employees could share the same dates, and one person's most recent date may not be anothers.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AncientAnt: This is not my answer. I only edited to format the code. For what it's worth, I upvoted Mikael Eriksson's answer as the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from payrates 
where date = (select max(dates) 
                from payrates);
```