# Finding a way to join on the latest range of dates?

Tags: sql, join

Sorry, I'm not even really sure how to title this question, so hopefully I can describe it.

I'm trying to query, either using a  join or subquery, and something's just not clicking.  My brain is getting mushier by the minute.

So, I have a table with sales by day per item.

Then I have a table with ranges of dates where the item was associated with a sale.

The issue is that there could have been 2-3 sale periods that overlapped that the item was associated to.  But, the sales will never have the same end date, and the sale with the end date that is latests (or Highest numerically) will have the true cost of that item during that period, ever if there was a different cost in the previous period that overlapped.

So **what can I do to return the cost of the item by day given this structure?**

```
Item sales by date
-----------
itemID  |  Sales  | Date
---------------------------
1          $4.00    3/29
1          $5.00    4/1
1          $6,00    4/3
```

---

```
Sale Periods and Item Costs
===========================
item ID | StartDate | EndDate  |  Cost In Period | PeriodID
-----------------------------------------------------------
1         3/27        4/2         $2.00            1
1         4/1         4/16        $1.90            2
```

---

You can see that sales 4/1, would appear to have two costs that could be associated, and I'd want to use the cost from the period that end later.

so the results would be

```
Item sales by date WITH COST
-----------
itemID  |  Sales  | Date | COST
--------------------------------
1          $4.00    3/29   $2.00
1          $5.00    4/1    $1.80
1          $6,00    4/3    $1.80
```

Comment: What RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server, ORacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED:
This may be close

```
SELECT ISBD.itemID, ISBD.Sales, ISBD.Date, SPIC.Cost
FROM ITemSalesByDate ISBD
LEFT JOIN  SalePeriodsandItemCosts SPIC
  ON SPIC.ItemID = ISBC.ItemID 
  AND SPIC.EndDate = 
   (SELECT max(SPIC2.ENDDATE) 
    FROM SalePeriodsandItemCosts SPIC2 
    WHERE SPIC2.ItemID = ISBD.ItemID)
```

one of my concerns though is the performance of the subquery  it may be faster to simply do a second join on salePeriodsandItemcosts for the max item ID and group by the other values.

Comment: This works except that in the sub query i also have to check that the Sales date (ISBD.Date) is between the SPIC2.StartDtae and SPIC2.ENDDATE

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is SQLServer, try:

```
with cte as
(select s.itemID, s.Sales, s.[Date], c.[Cost in Period],
        row_number() over (partition by s.itemID, s.[Date] 
                           order by c.EndDate desc) rn
 from sales s
 join costs c 
   on s.itemID = c.[item ID] and s.Date between c.StartDate and c.EndDate)
select itemID, Sales, [Date], [Cost in Period]
from cte
where rn=1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1ae3/1).

Comment: It's funny (kind of), that right after I posted this, i noticed that i had asked a question very similar to this before[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002898/trying-to-pull-most-recent-pay-rate-from-table) , and the solution used this approach.  i'm going to try this as well, and see if its faster.  i tried xQberts approach (with a slight) variation first, which does seem to work.

Comment: this is MS SQL Server 2005